# encoding problem with \verbatiminput : Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: verbatim, unicode, input-encodings

I'm trying to import some logs files using \verbatiminput to do a automatic report from our logs. I got some encoding problem.

My objective: import some logs files with various special char (included hidden one) as verbatim.

- I believed the file to be in ISO-8859-1. (the server OS is windows)
- I got a LOT of file. So the usual solution "rewrite it"/"look for the faulty char" is not an option.
- I run pdflatex from a mac osx.
- I converted the files with (notice the -c option to drop faulty char)

.

```
for file in ./test*/*.txt
do
  iconv -c -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf8 $file  > $file.n1
  mv -f $file.n1 $file 
done
```

My tex header:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

error message I got :

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:° not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

To solve the "degree" problem, I added

```
cat $file.n1 | tr '°' 'º' > $file.n2
```

then I got an other error on an other file, this time with an invisible char.

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

I first tried to not convert the file and import them as T1/latin1 or LY1/ascinew, but I got the error

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `latin1'.
```

on different files.

My question:

- Is there  a way to ignore/replace ALL the faulty char?
- from LaTeX ? from the shell ?
- using "tr" or "iconv" ?
- Am I doing something wrong when importing the files / doing the conversion?
- with which encoding will I have less problem ?

any help is welcome, as I am blocked on this since two days.

PS: My problem is not with the degree symbole in particular, but with unicode char that LaTeX cannot printout.

Comment: Very strange, but, at the end, I just remove the \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and the iconv then everything works fine. (using pdflatex). Thanks a lot for the answers, I did learn useful stuffs.

Comment: Well if your files are not utf8-encoded than if you use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` you are lying to LaTeX - and LaTeX doesn't like lies ;-). But you shouldn't remove inputenc completly (unless you are using an unicode engine like xetex). If you do it non-ascii-chars will only work partly. Load inputenc with the correct option (your encoding), and if you load files with another encoding than tell this LaTeX with the `\inputencoding` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can replace the faulty char.
You could replace `°` with `\ensuremath{^\circ}`

or add to your latex header:

```
\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B0}{\degree}
```

Or you could use `xelatex` then there is no need for `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` because it has full `utf8` support build in.

The encoding is all right Latex just doesn't know what to do with the unicode symbol `:D`

Comment: as I include the files as verbatim, changing the faulty char in the imported file will not help, no? I will look at the xelatex...

Comment: No this would be hard inside of verbatim. `XeLatex` should be the easiest option. Just remove the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` from your header and use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`. If you want to see the unicode characters make sure that you use a font that supports them. (The standard cmtt10 hasn't support)

Comment: You can use `\usepackage{xeCJK}` to get such a font.

Answer (score 4):

The character `°` is actually not included in the definitions make by the `utf8` module for `inputenc`.

```
\usepackage{textcomp} % for \textdegree
\usepackage{newunicodechar} % for \newunicodechar
\newunicodechar{°}{\textdegree}
```

Alternatively, you can resort to a "hand made symbol"

```
\newunicodechar{°}{\ensuremath{{}^\circ}}
```

that will work both in text and math mode (and `textcomp` is not needed).

The advantage of `newunicodechar` is that it doesn't require knowing the Unicode point of the character we want to define a command for.

Of course the "degree" case is an example: you can add all the characters you need.

However, if your files *are* Latin-1 encoded (ISO 8859-1), you can try switching to this encoding before inputting them:

```
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc} % utf8 is default
\newcommand{\latinoneverbatiminput}{%
  \begingroup\inputencoding{latin1}\verbatiminput{#1}\endgroup}
```

Then `\latinoneverbatiminput{file}` will use Latin-1 for `file`.

Comment: nice package. I always looked at a Unicode table for this.

Comment: @someonr That's why I wrote it: I'm lazy. :)

Comment: about the "degree" : it's working: I removed the extra "tr" from my  .sh. But How do I solve the invisible faulty char ?

Comment: You can look at the log file, for example with `LESSCHARSET=ascii less file`: search for `u8` and you'll find the UTF-8 representation of the character; for example the degree is `<C2><B0>`. Add it to your question, so that a recipe for dealing with it can be suggested.

Comment: I will keep in my notes the "\newunicodechar". nice function!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reencode your files. But you must declare/change the encoding of the files before loading them:

```
\begingroup
\inputencoding{whatever}
\verbatiminput{file}
\endgroup
```

I don't know what value you should use for "whatever". On windows I would at first try "ansinew" (latin1 has a less chars declared).