# Error: Unicode char \u8:φ not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: unicode

I have the following LaTeX document, saved in the UTF-8 character set encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
φΔδ汉
\end{document}
```

(it has 3 Greek characters followed by a Chinese one.) When I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
$ latex foo
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)
restricted \write18 enabled.
[...]
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:φ not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

How can I use these and other characters, in UTF-8 encoded `.tex` files?

Note: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40014/encoding-problem-with-verbatiminput-package-inputenc-error-unicode-char-u8) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/inputenc-error-unicode-char-u8-error-while-trying-to-write-a-degree-symbol) look like duplicates but they are slightly different and don't answer my question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `inputenc` package, even with the `utf8` option doesn't load all the Unicode tables. It loads only those for which it knows it will have to typeset some glyphs.

You have then to teach the proper environment, because each Unicode block requires a different TeX fonts (they have only 256 characters).

So your example works with `pdflatex`, but modified into the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{greek}{φΔδ}\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}汉\end{CJK}

\end{document}
```

This is admittedly largely impractical for extensive usage of characters belonging to different blocks, so it may be advisable to switch to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX that can use OpenType fonts.

[image]

### Important update

After release of Babel version 3.9, the `LGRx` encoding should not be used any more. Now LaTeX is able to interpret correctly UTF-8 characters for Greek out of the box, provided the Greek language is loaded with `babel`. So the example above becomes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{greek}{φΔδ}\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}汉\end{CJK}

\end{document}
```

Comment: there are two phis in unicode -- U+03C6 (the curly phi, shown in your answer) and U+03D5 (the straight phi, which is what the input looks like).  how can these be distinguished, and, for that matter, which one is actually wanted?

Comment: @barbarabeeton U+03C6 is the shape most commonly used this side of the Atlantic. I guess the one in the title is due to a font choice, because it is U+03C6, like the one in the error message.

Comment: if the one in the title is identified as U+03C6, then it's wrong.  sorry.  i've been trying to sort this out for 15 years, and the utc/unicode manual and i are in agreement. where can i find the images for what's in the font used for tex.sx titles?  if there's an error, i'd like to get it fixed.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't know what font is used; something more versed in HTML than I could know; but it's just the glyph the font uses for U+03C6, just try doing an edit and you'll see that the character in the title box is `φ` (U+03C6).

Comment: @barbarabeeton The font is (at least on my machine) Palatino and the glyph corresponding to U+03C6 has the “closed” shape, while the one for U+03D5 has the "open” one.

Comment: Can you explain what the CJK is doing here?

Comment: @einpoklum The OP wants a Chinese character

Answer (score 14):

`utf8` for `pdflatex` has only a limited subset of Unicode. Use `xelatex` with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Code2000}
%\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\begin{document}
φΔδ汉
\end{document}
```

[Code2000](http://www.fonts2u.com/code2000.police) can be replaced by another OpenType or TrueType font which has all that characters, eg. Arial Unicode.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when the tex editor file encoding and the document file encoding are not the same.

E.g. editor file encoding is ISO-8859-1, and the document has `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` command. Change the editor file encoding to UTF-8, and restart the editor.

(It is possible that your editor refers to *file* encoding as *font* encoding. For details, see the comments.)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! These aren't _font_ encodings, but _file_ encodings you're thinking of.

Comment: Hello! Thank you, precisely so. (My editor refers to it as _font_ encoding.)

Comment: Then I would not trust that editor anymore `;)`. (Which one is it?) The thing is, there is a concept called _font encodings_ in LaTeX, it's what you're dealing with when saying e.g. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: Texmaker. I am new here, and it is important to me to add correct answers. What is the etiquette here? Can I improve my answers after comments, or leave it as it is?

Comment: It's definitely a good idea to [edit] your answer, possibly with a little note that the edit resulted from comments, but often that's not even necessary. Thanks for caring! (As for Texmaker: That's the editor I use as well. I'll file a bug report later.)

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. Kind encounter with tex.sx :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to add my use case, which basically involves a manual install of `LGRx`:

Essentially, all I want is to be able to type units like `μW` directly in UTF-8 in the source `.tex` file (that is, I'd rather not type constructs like `\foreignlanguage{greek}{μ}W`); and I need to be using `pdflatex`.

Currently I'm on a machine with texlive 2011, which I cannot upgrade fully at the moment.

On texlive 2011, the combo:

- `[utf8x]{inputenc/x}` + `[LGR, T1]{fontenc}` + `{textcomp}`

generally works fine. Unfortunately, the problem is that additionally I need to be using `biblatex`, which chokes on the `ucs` package which `utf8x` loads.

So, I tried the `[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}` as recommended in the accepted answer - but it turns out, there is no `LGRx` encoding in texlive 2011 ...

So, after a bit of digging, this is what I ended up doing in `bash`:

```
wget http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LGR/lgrxenc.def -O /path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/lgrxenc.def
texhash
wget http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LGR/lgrenc.dfu -O /path/to/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/lgrenc.dfu
texhash
```

Note that you must call `texhash` (see [LaTeX/Installing Extra Packages: 4. Update your index - Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages#Installing_a_package)) otherwise `pdflatex` will not be able to find the newly downloaded files.

With that, now the combo

- `[utf8]{inputenc/x}` + `[LGRx, T1]{fontenc}` + `{textcomp}`

... works fine, like in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[LGRx, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}


\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} % just testing - is OK

\begin{document}

μW

\end{document}
```

Note that

- the [lgrxenc.def](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LGR/lgrxenc.def) I've downloaded is v0.6/2012-06-29 , and it contains `\DeclareTextSymbol{\textmu}{LGR}{109}` - while the latest [lgrxenc.def v0.8 2013-05-30](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lgrx/lgrxenc.def) is "backwards compatibility file for new lgrenc.def", and has fewer definitions (and `\textmu` is *not* present in it)
- the [lgrenc.dfu](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LGR/lgrenc.dfu) I've downloaded is v0.2 2012-06-27; the latest is [lgrenc.dfu v1.4.1 2013-07-18](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/language/greek/greek-inputenc/lgrenc.dfu) and it has now a different location in the tree - but they both contain `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03BC}{\textmu}`
- [textcomp.sty](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex2e/unpacked/textcomp.sty) is needed, as it defines `\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textmu}{TS1}`

Well, hope this helps someone,
Cheers!