# Writing Unicode in pdfLatex

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

It should be something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{megafont}
τέχνη (ΤΕΧΝΗ - technē)
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

I want to write the whole document in UTF8 not just a word like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73560/error-unicode-char-u8%CF%86-not-set-up-for-use-with-latex).

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: how to make that code work

Comment: Why do you need `CJKutf8`? are you writing in an East Asian language? Otherwise remove that package and the `CJK` environment and you'll be fine.

Comment: As you can see in the question that I linked `inputenc` doesn't load all unicode symbols.

Comment: If you want to use all of the more than 60.000 unicode symbols the answer is: with a lot work. In this case you should better use xelatex or lualatex. If you only want to use specific unicode range you should tell which one (and perhaps again consider to use xelatex or lualatex).

Comment: The question has an accepted answer, but I still don't understand what the question is. Partly because there is no question asked, but also because I don't understand what this has to do with unicode. This question is therefore unlikely to help future visitors, so I am voting to close.

Comment: I want to write the whole document in UTF8?

Comment: @Arturo Yes, quite doable for many cases but does depend on input and font support in the 8-bit world. You'll need to be more specific, in particular what glyph coverage you need. No one font covers everything even for Unicode engines!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Greek, not Chinese-Japanese-Korean (which is what CJK stands for).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{τέχνη}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use Latin characters for inputting Greek, but using a well defined translitteration scheme:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\textgreek{τέχνη}

 {\itshape \textgreek{τέχνη}} (\textgreek{ΤΕΧΝΗ} - \textgreek{t'eqnh})

\end{document}
```

[image]

See the documentation of `cbgreek` for the complete scheme:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work {\itshape \textgreek{τέχνη}} (ΤΕΧΝΗ - \textgreek{technē})

Comment: @Arturo If you need a full font family for Greek writing (italics, bold, etc.) for a large amount of Greek text, it would probably be much simpler to use xelatex or lualatex with a Unicode Greek font.

Comment: the LaTeX wikibook compiles with pdflatex and I want to know how.

Comment: @Arturo This compiles perfectly with pdflatex on TeX Live 2014 (or 2013). Update your TeX distribution.

Comment: what do you mean with "this" τέχνη or  {\itshape \textgreek{τέχνη}} (ΤΕΧΝΗ - \textgreek{technē})?

Comment: @Arturo It works, provided you use the correct input.

Comment: {\itshape \textgreek{τέχνη}} ({\ttfamily TEXNH} - techn\={e})

Comment: @Arturo It's useless to insist using an unsupported syntax. *If* the main language is Greek, you don't need to use `\textgreek`, but you need `\textlatin` for Latin characters. Or you switch to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.